# Connected dots plot in R

Tags: r

```
> s
       V2 V4 V6 V7 V9  V10 [...]
crp1   22 18 18 18 24 0.00  
crp2   0  53 11 0  0  5.39  
rep1L  1  0  1  2  0  4.00
```

Hello everyone,
S is my dataset in the wide format, from which I have excluded all columns with NA values. I want to make a plot with crp1 and crp2 as dots on the x-axis connected by a line,
the color being defined by "rep1L" value (from 1 to 5).

Thanks for your help,
Nathalie

Comment: Best would be to first convert your data to long format. Afterwards I would suggest have a look at some tutorials like e.g. http://uc-r.github.io/cleveland-dot-plots.

Comment: It looks like you're fairly new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput(head(dataObject)))`. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).